# Java MOD operator returns negative value

Tags: java, negative-number, modulo

I have this method:

```
private static int generateNo(int randomNo, int value){
    return   ((randomNo*value)%256);
}
```

in my example
 randomNo = 17719
 qValue = 197920

When I calculate it with calculator the returned value should be 224, however, when I run the program it returns -32.

can anyone explain it please.

Comment: The multiplication has overflowed integer's range.

Comment: And the modulus operator works like division, so it'll give a negative answer if one argument is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hint. If you have unexpected negative value when multiply (or sum) numbers, mostly this is number overflow:

```
private static int generateNo(int randomNo, int value) {
    return (int)(((long)randomNo * value) % 256);
}
```

Comment: This works, but I think it would be useful to explain to OP _why_ it works.

Answer (score 2):

Java is in the camp of using a *signed remainder* instead of the operation that is usually meant modulus (the non-negative remainder of Euclidean division). Fortunately for powers of two there is a really easy fix: use bitwise `&`. That's easier to think about anyway, since it's a trivial operation on bits, instead of the result of a complicated division algorithm.

For example:

```
private static int generateNo(int randomNo, int value) {
    return randomNo * value & 255;
}
```

This cannot possibly have a negative result since `& 255` guarantees that only the low 8 bits of the result can be set, so the result is for sure in the range [0..255].

Letting the multiplication wrap first is OK if you want some of the lower bits of the result, as here (the lowest 8). It does not work properly if you want to compute `(x * y) MOD p` where `p` is not a power of two, because then (after working around Java's signed remainder thing) the actual computation becomes (due to wrapping) `((x * y) MOD 2³²) MOD p`. IFF `p` divides 2³² (ie iff `p` is a power of two not exceeding 2³²) *then* that simplifies down to just `(x * y) MOD p`.

Or with a more bit-level view: the bits of the product are the lowest 32 bits of the "full" product (the full product of two 32 bit integers has 64 bits), of course if we only need those bits (or some subset of them, such as the lowest 8) then that's fine. But if the result we want would depend on the 32 high bits of the product, then obviously we would need to compute those bits.  `(x * y) MOD p` where `p` is not a power of two would depend on all bits of the full product.

Answer (score 1):

`17719*197920 = 3506944480`, which is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

As such, the multiplication overflows the range of int, and the result is `-788022816`.

Hence, taking the modulus results in a negative result.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here.

1. Multiplying two `int`s together can result in a number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647), which wraps around to being a negative number.
2. Applying the modulus operator on a positive and a negative number results in a negative number.

You need to think about how you want this function to work given edge case values, like very large integers or negative numbers.

What should `generateNo(-100, 50)` produce, for example?

You may want to ensure your values are positive before doing the modulus, like this:

```
Math.abs(randomNo * value) % 256
```

However, this actually has a really interesting edge case where `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` because it overflows.

Instead, use `Math.abs` on the *result*:

```
Math.abs((randomNo * value) % 256)
```

I'll also offer some general critique about this function. The names don't really explain what it does. Why `generateNo`? No doubt there are many ways to generate an number. I would suggest a more specific name.

The arguments, `randomNo` and `value` are also problematic. Why does `generateNo` care if the first argument is random or not?

Specifying what you want to happen more clearly, and having names that describe those things, may make it easier to think about.

I also suggest, when having issues like this, to break down the steps so you understand what is going on. Something like:

```
private static int generateNo(int randomNo, int value){
    final int product = randomNo * value;
    final int result = product % 256;

    // Breakpoint or System.out.println here, to understand the values...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note `Math.abs` can produce a negative result in an unusual case.  Also, **typically**, the result after an integer overflow will be nonsense. In this special case you can use `(randomNo*value) & 0xff`.

Comment: Hah, you're referring to the edge case where `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`? Never occurred to me, but that's actually pretty funny, and would be an amazing (and totally possible) bug in this case. I'll edit the answer to suggest using `Math.abs` on the _result_. That's great.

Comment: The fact is though, the OP should really just being thinking more about what this function is supposed to do, and probably some research into integer overflow and the modulus operator.